# Make temporary Files downloadable from Website

Tags: php, html, download

On a webservice I'm developing, a user should be able to download his data in a HTML file. This file contains everything (including images as base64).

Now to make the user download this, I would have to create the file and save it on my webserver. Afterwards, I'd have to delete it using a cronjob, because I can't figure out when the download is complete.

Is there another way? Would it be possible to download a file to the user which does not physically exist on my webserver, but gets somehow created temporarily?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not sure I've got the point. But why do not simply process desired data via constant PHP-script (gathering all inside script) and then send content to user? This will exactly match one-download-time concept (with no need to create something or delete it then)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo that's exactly what I was looking for, but I didn't realise how to do, but the answers showed me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the WWW is concerned, there is no such thing as a file. There are just HTTP resources.

The server might get the data from a file, it might not.

Just output the data for the file from your PHP program. (i.e. by putting it outside `<?php` and `?>` or using `echo` or any other technique that causes PHP to output something).

You need to make sure you use the right `Content-Type` header, but since you are using HTML, that is `text/html` which is the default.

You can add a `Content-Disposition` header if you want the user to be prompted to save their download somewhere instead of rendering the downloaded HTML in the browser window.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='foo.html'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Well, the last line `readfile(...)` does what I don't want to do (I don't want a physical file). But instead, if I output the content instead of this line, this also works? That would be exactly what I want!